# Angular module (routing) with URL prefix

Tags: angular, angular-routing, angular-router

I have following router nesting in module SampleModule

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: 'samples',
    component: SampleListComponent,
    children: [
      {
        path: ':id',
        component: SampleDetailsComponent,
        children: [
         {
        ...
```

Then in my app component, I have next definition:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-2">
      <dashboard></dashboard>
    </div>
    <div class="col-10">
      <router-outlet></router-outlet>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

In my dashboard, I have menu items which use router link to navigate to a specific module router (ex /samples)

URL is root/samples which continues to root/samples/3 ...

That all works really good and the components from that module are correctly displayed.

The problem is when I try to provide some documentation page which is separated into topics, different URL prefixes ...

So the URL I would like to have when navigating is the following:

root/modules-documentation/samples ...

If I navigate to samples module in documentation component it again navigates to root and my documentation component is lost. Is it possible to somehow wrap that module without changing anything in the module?

Answer (score 0):

I've managed to fix it like this.

DocumentationModule

```
    const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: 'documentation-modules', component: LandingPageComponent,
    children: [
      ...SAMPLE_ROUTES
    ]
  },
];
```

SAMPLE_ROUTES:

```
export const SAMPLE_ROUTES: Routes = [
  {
    path: 'samples',
    component: SampleListComponent,
    children: [
      {
        path: ':id',
        component: SampleDetailsComponent,
        children: [
          {
            path: 'depth3',
            component: SampleDepth3Component,
            children: [
              {
                path: 'depth4',
                component: SampleDepth4Component,
                children: [
                  {
                    path: 'depth5',
                    component: SampleDepth5Component,
                  }
                ]
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      }

    ]
  }
];
```